# How to upgrade react-native version from 0.68.0 to latest version 0.69.1? I have tried but got an error

Tags: react-native

I have tried to upgrade react native version from 0.68.0 to latest version 0.69.1, by using this command `npx react-native upgrade`, it throws an error below is picture link (error)

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nwKDW0r5-LrJhazqXJaBN70SzFg2fsXY/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjTGe.png)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.0",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^4.2.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it below steps maybe it works.

-- Delete node modules
Also,go to IOS folder & delete  `pods` folder  & `podfile.lock`

-- Then do the:
npm install,
cd ios, pod install,
-- then do the :
`npx react-native upgrade`
or else
you can define specific version also, like
`npx react-native upgrade 0.69`

- it works.